# Matplotlib live graph appearing with 0 axes?

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, animation, graph

Below is the code I have to create a live updating graph that reads values from a `csv` file. Evertime I run it it says the figure is created with 0 axes. what am I missing?

```
def animate(i):
    data = pd.read_csv(tool1path)
    count = range(20)
   
    
    
    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(data,count, label='Jet Height')
 
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.tight_layout()
    
ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=1000)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your code this way:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def animate(i):
    data = pd.read_csv(tool1path)
    count = range(20)
   
    
    
    plt.cla()
    ax.plot(data,count, label='Jet Height')
 
    ax.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.tight_layout()
    
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

In this way you instantiate the `ax` (where you plot your data inside the `animate` function) and the `fig` (that you pass as a parameter to the `FuncAnimation`) before calling the `FuncAnimation`.